# Arrange imported columns after calculated columns in PowerBI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to move imported columns **after** calculated columns? I know I can create a new table by using `Selectcolumns`, but that'll just balloon the size of the PowerBI data file. Seems like such a miss on Microsoft's part

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply start all calculated columns with an underscore (*judging by your username, you seem to be fond of unnecessary underscores*)
2. Another option would be to put imported and calculated columns into different [Display folders](https://powerbidocs.com/2020/10/25/creating-display-folder-in-power-bi/) (such a miss on user's part)